# React router does not show the homepage and all other pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have this code and it does not display the homepage, that is the page that comes at '/'. But if I insert the <home /> tag after the <navbar /> tag, the homepage comes.

```
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./componets/navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages";
import About from "./pages/about";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact elements={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" exact elements={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There's no longer any `exact` prop on the `Route` component, but this is ignored. I don't see any overt issue with the code you've shared. Are there any errors in the console? What debugging have you done? Can you produce a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this route matching and rendering issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I haven't seen `elements` before, I though it was `component`.

Comment: As @Crustyeyelids said, I believe it is `component` instead of `elements`. This post may help you https://dev.to/raaynaldo/react-router-three-route-rendering-methods-component-render-and-children-2eng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error. It was simple. It should be `element` and not `elements`. So the `s` was the error. Thanks again.